# 2 questions sci-fi stories from the 1950s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The first is a Ray Bradbury story about rich American tourists in Mexico doing the "ugly american" thing. But then nuclear war destroys their homeland, while the story chronicles their helpless descent from rich overlords to penniless vagrants in a suddenly strange land.

The second is about 3 astronaut-explorers who land on a new planet who land about a mile away from an obviously artificial construct, a massive cube. Each starts setting up his equipment for the surveys they need to make. The first to finish rides over to the cube and just sits facing it. The second to finish wonders what the first is doing just sitting in front of that cube, rides over to it, and joins him sitting staring at it.
The third astronaut finishes his setup, and though uneasy about his companions obsession with the cube, he also goes to join them, and becomes entranced in his turn. The 3 of them sit in comfortable silence, entranced by the visions the cube shows each of them, waiting for the trapper to come back and collect them.
Seeing people with their cell-phones, I realize Steve Jobs invented the cube, and now we all wait for the trapper to come for us.

Comment: What are the astronauts riding? Are they on horseback?

Comment: Sorry about the mess here I didn't see ___both___ stories have since been asked about [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269850/58193) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269846/58193). I'll preserve this one as it has an answer but have it closed so no more can be added here. If you think you know the answer to either of these questions please visit the linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is *[Casablanca](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58755)* by Thomas Disch

From this [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/ThomasMDisch) article:

> American tourists in Morocco in the story "Casablanca" quickly become
> unwanted foreigners after the US is annihilated in a nuclear exchange.
> The reason? The companies behind their credit cards and travelers
> checks have also been destroyed, and they only have small amounts of
> the local currency.

which seems like a good match to what you're looking for.

Comment: More likely it's Bradbury's "The Highway", set in Mexico, which is what the question asks about i.e. Bradbury and Mexico, not Disch and Morocco. "What do they mean, the world?"

Comment: *The Highway* is similar, but it doesn't *chronicle their helpless descent from rich overlords to penniless vagrants* so I don't think it could be the story the OP remembers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You may be right. Then again, ID questions sometimes have misremembered details. Mexico, Morocco, third world countries starting with an "M", who can keep them straight? These questions would be a lot easier to answer if askers would give us the (correct) author's name. I tend to discount the OP's guess, especially when they guess some very prominent author like Asimov or Bradbury.

Comment: First - Probably Bradbury "And, I'm afraid.Can't help on the second the Rock Cried Out". Anthologised in "The Day It Rained Forever.

Comment: Thank you, Organic Marble, for title; and Mark Stone, for where to find it. This was the first Bradbury story I ever read, and made me a confirmed SF fan.

Comment: @user985675: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].