# Author and Title of a SF story from 60s, most probably read it in Fantasy and Science Fiction, possibly Analog or If

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration, astronauts

3 male astronaut-explorers land on a new planet about a mile away from an obviously artificial construct, a massive cube. Each starts setting up his equipment for the surveys they need to make. The first to finish rides over to the cube and just sits facing it, in full view of the other two back at their ship.The second to finish wonders what the first is doing just sitting in front of that cube, also rides over to it, and joins him sitting staring at it.

The third astronaut finishes his setup, and though uneasy about his companions obsession with the cube, he also goes to join them, and becomes entranced in his turn. The 3 of them sit in comfortable silence, entranced by the visions the cube shows each of them, waiting for the trapper to come back and collect them.

To be honest, the story did not impress me that much at the time, but since the development of the smartphone, and the effect it has on so many of its users, I can see it was very prophetic, that Steve Jobs went and invented the cube of this story.

This story certainly was **not** the Arthur C Clarke short (can't remember its name either) that eventually became "2001: A Space Odyssey", that ended with with the so-memorable line

> The old are often very jealous of the young.

Comment: The A. C. Clarke story you quoted from is "The Sentinel". I don't see what it has to do with your actual question.

Comment: In the 60s you were reading F&SF, Analog, and If, but not If's sister magazine Galaxy?

Comment: Of course I read Galaxy, but could not recall its name as I was typing the title.  Thanks for The Sentinel, the connection for me is that both stories dealt with lures, or snares, of a sort.