# Ray Bradbury story from the 1950s, effect of nuclear war on Americans in Mexico

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

This story is neither Bradbury's "The Highway" (though I think it likely that was an earlier, and much weaker, attempt to deal with this story's theme); nor is it Thomas Disch's "Casablanca", which dealt with the same theme, but in a much more personal manner.

What made this story so brutally effective was its complete depersonalization, it dealt entirely in stereotypes; the rich, loud, obnoxious American family on vacation in Mexico, their enormous car (with those 50s fins etc), the loud music from its radio, their ostentatious condescension to the locals, the locals poverty and resentful fawning on the Americans' dollars.

Then, nuclear war destroyed the USA.

And in a horrible parody of its opening paragraphs, the story inverts itself. With their dollars and credit cards now useless, reality wastes no time intruding itself on the protagonists, their fine clothes and shoes traded for a meal and local rags, likewise their watches and jewelry, and finally their car runs out of gas and, now useless to them, is traded for a meal.

While loud, obnoxious Mexicans tool around in their once beautiful automobile, a group of penniless Anglo vagrants stand by the roadside, staring wistfully at their recent past, in terror at their impending future.

OK, I was at a very impressionable age when I read it, but no other story has ever come close to affecting me like this did, the terrible, remorseless logic of it; the inversion of the oblivious, uncaring Americans' unawareness of Mexican reality into the oblivious, uncaring Mexicans' unawareness of the Americans' new reality.

Nor is it "And the Rock Cried Out". The story I seek takes place entirely in the one small town, and there is no element of hostility in it. The locals remain friendly. But they are no longer interested in the Americans. With their money worthless, the Americans have nothing to offer the locals but their possessions, and the locals value those only as novelties. The role reversal reveals the essential similarity of the Mexicans and the Americans, that neither cared anything about the other, but what they could get from them, beyond that just benevolent indifference. Maybe not Bradbury, but I could have sworn...

The ending of the story is very like that of the 2004 Afghan movie Stray Dogs, the little girl standing alone on the road in the deepening twilight, the same sense of impending, but unmentioned, disaster.

Comment: So if not "The Highway" then probably also not "And the Rock Cried Out," which starts out _after_ the war, when the couple are trying to find somewhere safe to go.

Comment: It’s not clear if you’re sure it’s a Ray Bradbury. I think I’ve read all of his - but maybe not. This one doesn’t ring a bell, although it does seem similar to stuff he wrote during the *Martian Chronicles* years.

Comment: @DavidW Even though the details don't match up perfectly, I'm 99% sure it's And the Rock Cried Out.  You should write an answer about it.

Comment: "And the Rock Cried Out" doesn't fit the description of *it dealt entirely in stereotypes* since it deals quite sympathetically with its protagonists (Jack and Leonora Webb), but I agree that @DavidW should post it as an answer in case the OP has misremembered the story slightly.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a perfect match, but I've been encouraged to post "[And the Rock Cried Out](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64822)" (1953) by Ray Bradbury.

The story opens *in media res* with John and Leonora Webb fleeing in their car through small towns and stretches of jungle.  On the road they encounter bladed traps designed to shred tires and force them to stop.  Invisible people in the jungle fire poison darts at them.

They have a newspaper that announces the apparent destruction of the global north:

> **4 OCTOBER 1963: UNITED STATES, EUROPE SILENT!**
>
> *The radios of the U.S.A. and Europe are dead.  There is a great silence.  The War has spent itself.*
>
> It is believed that most of the population of the United States is dead.  It is believed that most of Europe, Russia and Siberia are equally decimated.  The day of the white people of the earth is over and finished.

The Webbs are trying to leave, all Americans having been given 24 hours to leave the country, but the neighbouring country won't take them either.

> 'You don't understand,' said Webb, touching the first man's elbow.  'We've *got* to get through.'
>
> The man shook his head. 'Passports are no longer good.  Why should you want to leave our country, anyway?'
>
> 'It was announced on the radio.  All Americans to leave the country, immediately.'
>
> 'Ah, *si si*,' all three soldiers nodded and leered at each other with shining eyes.
>
> 'Or be fined or imprisoned, or both,' said Webb.
>
> 'We could let you over the border, but Juatala would give you twenty-four hours to leave also.  If you don't believe me, listen!'  The guard turned and called across the border, 'Aye, there!  Aye!'
>
> In the hot sun, forty yards distant, a pacing man turned, his rifle in his arms.
>
> 'Aye there, Paco, you want these two people?'
>
> '*No, gracias - gracias, no*,' replied the man, smiling.

The soldiers take their pesos, the rest of their money no longer being worth anything, but only send them back.  Then they lose their car, when it runs out of gas and nobody will sell them any.

> 'Watch it, here comes a car - we'd better...'
>
> They half turned, yelled, and jumped.  They fell away from the highway and lay watching the automobile hurtle past at seventy miles an hour.  Voices sang, men laughed, men shouted, waving.  The car sped away into the dust and vanished around a curve, blaring its double horns again and again.

They lose basically everything but the clothes on their back; the manager of the hotel they stay in, who remembers John, shelters them for a night, but steals John's gun.  In the end, having no other real option, they go to face the people of the town.

The story, in the Bradbury collection *The Day It Rained Forever*, is available to borrow at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dayitrainedforev0000brad_l1x4/).